# end of statement expected in vb.net while storing value to the object?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Protected Sub Email_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs)
    Dim objExport As ClsItextSharp = New ClsItextSharp()
    Dim strPath As String = ""
    Dim objReport As Report = New Report()
    objReport = (Telerik.Reporting.Report)RViewer.Report
    strPath = CreatePDfwithPath1(objReport)
    Dim docType As String = "EncounterNote"
    Dim Imgop As ImageOperations = New ImageOperations()
    Dim Path As String = Imgop.EncriptString(strpath)
    Response.Redirect("../EMail/SendMail.aspx?send=M&Type=nothing&strpath=" + Path + "")
End Sub
```

end of statement expected in vb.net while storing value to the object? getting error on  objReport = (Telerik.Reporting.Report)RViewer.Report.

Answer (score 3):

What is this, C#?

```
objReport = (Telerik.Reporting.Report)RViewer.Report
```

I guess you want to cast it:

```
Dim objReport = CType(RViewer.Report, Telerik.Reporting.Report)
```